# New Architecture with Dagger and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-architecture-components

I have a problem with New Architecture components in Kotlin, when I create ViewModel component in recomended way (in onCreate() method) the result is as suposed:

- after activity orientation changes, I got the same instance of ViewModel as before

Here is the way i create this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list)

    val arrayMap = ArrayMap<Class<out ViewModel>, ViewModel>()
    arrayMap.put(ListViewModel::class.java, ListViewModel(webApi, repoDao))
    val factory = ViewModelFactory(arrayMap)
    listViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(ListViewModel::class.java)

    listViewModel.items.observe({ this.lifecycle }) {
        Toast.makeText(this, it?.joinToString { it + " " } ?: "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

But when I have used Dagger for inject ListViewModel I got new instance of ListViewModel every time Activity was recreated. Here is a code of Dagger ListActivityModel.

```
@Module @ListActivityScopeclass ListActivityModule {
@Provides
@ListActivityScope
fun provideListViewModel(webApi: WebApi, repoDao: RepoDao, listActivity: ListActivity): ListViewModel {
    val arrayMap = ArrayMap<Class<out ViewModel>, ViewModel>()
    arrayMap.put(ListViewModel::class.java, ListViewModel(webApi, repoDao))
    val factory = ViewModelFactory(arrayMap)
    val result =  ViewModelProviders.of(listActivity, factory).get(ListViewModel::class.java)
    return result
}
```

}
Then ListActivity onCreate() method looks like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list)
    listViewModel.items.observe({ this.lifecycle }) {
        Toast.makeText(this, it?.joinToString { it + " " } ?: "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

And there is what I have notice after logging:

```
D/ListActivity: ---> onCreate() ListActivity: = [com.example.dom.app.new_arch.ListActivity@a0f2778]
D/ListActivity: ---> onCreate() listViewModel: = [com.example.dom.app.new_arch.ListViewModel@54a8e51]

//Activity orientation changes

E/ViewModelStores: Failed to save a ViewModel for com.example.dom.app.new_arch.ListActivity@a0f2778
D/ListActivity: ---> onCreate() ListActivity: = [com.example.dom.app.new_arch.ListActivity@6813433]
D/ListActivity: ---> onCreate() listViewModel: = [com.example.dom.app.new_arch.ListViewModel@55cf3f0]
```

The error I have received :

> ViewModelStores: Failed to save a ViewModel for

comes from Android class HolderFragment with package android.arch.lifecycle.

There is something what I missed working with Dagger and new arch components?

Comment: AndroidInjection.inject() creates a new component for each new activity instance. This is specifically why I do not use it.

Comment: There is not a problem, becouse ViewModel are provided by static factory method:

ViewModelProviders.of(listActivity, factory).get(ListViewModel::class.java)

Comment: I faced the same issue, for unknown reason creating a viewmodel in a module using `dagger-android-support` leads to `ViewModelStores` fails

Comment: @IsmaelDiVita did you find any solution or issue where it is described in detail?

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the order of dagger injection and activity creation.  The view model implementation relies on a non-visual fragment for identity.  By injecting the viewModelProvider before the activity has completed onCreate it is unable to complete this association.

Since `super.onCreate` does not likely depend on things you are injecting try injecting after the call to `super.onCreate` and you should be fine.

I had this exact same issue and solved it by this change in order.

Specifically from your code instead of:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list)
```

go with:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list)
```

JP

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by only providing the `ViewModelFactory` using Dagger. Then it gets injected in the activity and you call `ViewModelProviders.of(listActivity, factory).get(ListViewModel::class.java)` from there. The reason your approach doesn't work is that `AndroidInjection.inject()` will create the ViewModel before onCreate, which leads to undefined behavior.

Also see: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/202

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is correct. I known your solution but I was trying to provide ViewModel by Dagger to avoid boilerplate code in onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `AndroidInjection.inject()` because it creates a new Dagger component. I create an Dagger Component in the Application class and I use that component instance to call inject in all other places of the app. This way your singletons are initialized only one time.